# @font-face not loading custom font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to use a custom font (.oft) that I have uploaded into my font folder in my filesystem.

I've declared the font in CSS with the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: '400'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('../font/400ml-Regular.otf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

and called it with :

```
.intro .slogan {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: '400';
}
```

My index.html page is in the root folder (var/www/html) and the css and font are in /var/www/html/css and /var/www/html/font respectively (so i think the '..' in the src is correct). I've also added the following to .htaccess

```
AddType font/otf .otf
```

but i'm still not even able to see it loading in developer tools.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: You need more font formats to make it work :)

Comment: Hi Bojan - could you please elaborate? I found the font online at : http://www.okilla.com/521/resource-typography-400ml-type/

Comment: You will also need a 400ml-Regular.ttf, 400ml-Regular.eot to work in the most commonly used browsers. That's what @BojanPetkovski is trying to say to you.

Comment: Not all browsers support or use the `.otf` format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make @font-face work across different browsers and OP you need to make it like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: '400';
  src: url('400ml-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('400ml-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('400ml-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('400ml-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('400ml-Regular.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Use a fontface generator to make different font formats. Try [fontsquirel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) or simillar :)

Comment: thanks for this - still no luck with fontsquirel and still not working :-(

Comment: strange thing is that none of them are coming up in sources in dev tools

Comment: You can check where is the font file uploaded. If you are uploading them via ftp using filezilla right click on the file and copy url to clipboard :)

Comment: i can see them in my terminal so know they are in the right place

Comment: does it matter where in the css i've made the @font-face declaration? mine is at the top

Comment: At the top is perfect. I guess your issue is with the folders where you have the fonts are from where you are calling them.

Comment: thought so - any advice ? its '..' to go up one level right?